# Undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I keep getting this error and I'm not sure why.

Here is my user controller right now:

```
def show
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
end
```

and what I have tried

```
@user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])

@user  = User.find(params[:id])
```

And my current HTML:

```
<li><%= link_to "Profile", user_path(@user, show) %></li>
```

and what I have tried:

```
<li><%= link_to "Profile", user_path(@user) %></li>

<li><%= link_to "Profile", user_path(@user.id) %></li>

<li><%= link_to "Profile", "/users/#{@user.id}" %></li>

<li><%= link_to "Profile", user_path %></li>

<li><%= link_to "Profile", user_show_path %></li>
```

Help appreciated. Thanks!

`rake routes`
[routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm4XC.png)

Comment: could you please do `rake routes` and  post `routes` of the application please , it would be more clear then

Comment: @chanakyadevraj I posted a picture of the routes

Comment: please check the name of the controller and its file name 
 controller name must be `UsersController`
and the name of the file shall be `users_controller.rb`

Comment: Don't post a picture of the routes; post the routes :( Edited to only include the ones we actually care about. And include the section of the `routes.rb` file.

Comment: if your every attempt fails then firstly try to find the `User` in rails console via `rails c` and fire 
`User.all` and spot the user record with if any, the guess would be there might be no `User` with that identity as [Arsen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5328417/arsen) suggested, `User` with the `params[:id]` is definitely `nil`

Comment: In any case, the issue is that you're *calling* `id` on something that's nil, somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind: `find_by` can return nil. So you have to check it before use.

```
def show
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
    unless @user
      render status: 404, nothing: true
    end
end
```

I think it's your case. `find_by` just returns nil

Comment: Hmm, now it says "No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]" on this line: `<li><%= link_to "Profile", user_path(@user) %></li>` and when I change it to `user_path(@user.id)` it says it's nil again

Comment: @kdl So your user is nil?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more details. We need to make sure that the user you're trying to access a view (user) that actually exists. You can check out by doing something along those lines:

```
$ rails console --sandbox
Loading development environment in sandbox (Rails 4.2.1)
Any modifications you make will be rolled back on exit
2.2.3 :001 > User.all.count
   (12.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
 => 2
2.2.3 :002 > id = User.first.id
  User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => 3
2.2.3 :003 > app.user_path(id: id)
 => "/users/3"
2.2.3 :004 >
```

Make sure `User.all.count` returns a number bigger than 0. If it's 0 then there are no users and you need to create one.

Comment: I have done that already, there is a user and I can even go to 'users/1' and it takes me to the show page

Answer (score 0):

okay, Here's the catch, i see that you have used the gem [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and you are trying to perform `CRUD` on `USER` so devise default routes that helps users session control of logging in and out is overriding traditional `users` behaviour.
 please refer [How To: Manage users through a CRUD interface](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface)
 or please refer earlier post 
[Devise registration controller conflict with my own “registrations” controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22879222/do-i-need-a-users-controller-when-using-devise-in-rails)
 i hope that clears you all doubts
Cheers

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a ton. I had to add `user_path(current_user)` which Devise gives you instead of trying to grab the id.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add `user_path(current_user)` instead of trying to grab the id. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Glad it helped you ! Cheers :)